# How to Undelete A Post Deleted by System or Community?

Tags: support, deleted-questions, undelete

[NOTE: Not a duplicate post]

I posted in the Graphic Design stack exchange and my post got automatically deleted by "Community". I read [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that) but it doesn't have the answer to my question, and I couldn't find any other SE questions that offer an effective answer, so I'm creating "this" new post.

My question is two-fold:

How can I undelete one of my questions that was deleted by "System" or "Community" user?

AND

If that's not possible, would I be better off just reposting?

Here is the post that got deleted:

[How to find the vertical midpoint of a Gimp image or canvas?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/72056/how-to-find-the-vertical-midpoint-of-a-gimp-image-or-canvas-solved?noredirect=1#comment109909_72056)

Thanks

Comment: From the "How can I undelete one of my posts" section of the question you linked and said didn't have the answer: _"Normally, if your deleted post is not self-deleted, you can't undelete it yourself (though you may be able to vote to undelete). An exception: if an answer is deleted from Low Quality review queue by "Recommend Deletion" votes, without three trusted users voting to delete, then it can be undeleted by the author."_

Comment: Now, that _does_ leave the question of how it was deleted- You can check this by going to "graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/posts/72056/timeline" which you should be able to see as the author of the post. That will give you the timeline, which should help identify why it was deleted.

Comment: @Kendra Thanks! I checked the timeline per your suggestion and looks like the first person to see it downvoted it. What can be done?

Comment: If that's what caused the deletion, then you'll have to either make your case to users who can undelete it or flag and make your case to a mod- It sounds like your question was cleaned up by the roomba. The post Shadow closed this as a duplicate of is spot on for this.

Comment: @Kendra what do you mean "Shadow closed this"? I googled and didn't find any results for that exact term.

Comment: Shadow Wizard closed this question (the one we're commenting on) as duplicate of a different question (not the one you linked), which you can find the link to at the top of your question. Sorry if I was unclear.

Comment: @Kendra Thanks for the clarification! The "duplicate" has very good information. I'm going to try editing my post and then flagging for a moderator.

Comment: You don't need to flag yet. If you think it's not a duplicate please explain and I can also reopen it with a single vote. (In its current state it's 100% duplicate though.)

Comment: @ShadowWizard yes I agree it is a duplicate. Do I need to "unflag" it or something? I'm new to the whole flagging thing. What is the protocol for duplicates? Should I leave my post up for the record, but add a note that I realize it is a duplicate?

Comment: Just leave it be, duplicates are useful for searching. No need to confirm or anything. Cheers!